# Devanagari counters in package expex subexamples

Tags: polyglossia, linguistics, examples, expex

I need Devanagari counters in package `expex`.

```
%!TeX TS-Program=xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{marathi}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=devanagarinumerals]{Shobhika}
\usepackage{expex}

\begin{document}
\pex
\a\begingl
\gla रामः आम्रफलम् खादति//
\glb राम आंबा खातो//
\glft राम आंबा खातो.//
\endgl
\a\begingl
\gla रामः आम्रफलम् खादति//
\glb राम आंबा खातो//
\glft राम आंबा खातो.//
\endgl
\xe
\end{document}
```

This generates a decent output, but unfortunately the second level items are in English. I want Devanagari counters. (अ, आ, इ, ई, उ, ऊ, ए, ऐ, ओ, औ, अं, अः) How to achieve it?

Comment: ExPex unfortunately uses a weird trick using `\char` to format alpha labels. It may not be trivial to make it use regular LaTeX methods.

Comment: Do you mean it can't be changed?

Comment: I'm not saying it's impossible, but because of the way it formats example numbers, it might not be very easy.

Comment: It turns out not to be too difficult after all!

Comment: The `babel` language files provide a way to map `\alph` counters to Hindi letters, but as of June 2020, this is not available for Marathi.

Comment: That is, the Hindi language file supports `alph=alphabetic`, but Marathi does not.

Comment: @Davislor as Alan already said, `expex` defines its own counters. So `alph=alphabetic` won't work. By the way `alph` is renewed in polyglossia also. So for nested enumeration in Marathi `polyglossia` serves better. Try this - `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\babelprovide[import, main,mapdigits,alph=alphabetic]{hindi}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari,Renderer=HarfBuzz]{Shobhika}
\usepackage{expex}

\begin{document}
\pex
\a\begingl
\gla रामः आम्रफलम् खादति//
\glb राम आंबा खातो//
\glft राम आंबा खातो.//
\endgl
\xe
\end{document}`

Comment: @Niranjan I see in chapter 8 of the manual commands to display Devanagari numerals in `polyglossia`, and to select alphabetic enumeration in some other scripts, but nothing about Devanagari? If there’s a package option to redefine `\alph` in `polyglossia, I must’ve overlooked it? But that’d be handy.

Comment: @Davislor I don't think I understand your point.

Comment: @Davislor From TL 2019 onwards, `gloss-marathi.ldf` has included a reimplementation of `\alph` as well as numerals but it's not a separate option but happens automatically if you choose `numerals=Devanagari` (the default).

Comment: @Davislor Defining new counters in `babel` is straightforward. See https://github.com/latex3/babel/wiki/Using-%5Cbabelprovide-to-modify-or-extend-locales#new-counters .

Comment: Here is a link to an example of how to (re)define list counters with `babel`: https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/74#issuecomment-642133525 .

Comment: @AlanMunn Thank you. I hadn’t known that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ExPex allows you to stipulate a list of items for a label list, so we can simply define a `labeltype` called `devanagari` and set it to the list of the corresponding alpha labels. I've used the width parameter from the uppercase alpha labels; this might not be appropriate for the Devanagari labels, so adjust the `labelwidth` accordingly.

The `labelgen` key can be thought of as a function that provides the mapping between the counter of the subexample to its label. It accepts four values: `char`, `number`, `romannumber` or `list`.  Using `char` will give you the equivalent of `\alph` in LaTeX, but because ExPex doesn't implement it using `\alph` it won't work with language definitions that redefine `\alph` like `polyglossia` or `babel`. The `number` and `romannumber` values are self-explanatory. The `list` value tells ExPex to consult an ordered list of characters to construct the label.  This is the recommended solution for non-Latin alphabets.

ExPex also uses a somewhat idiosyncratic method for specifying the label and reference format. These are the keys `labelformat` and `fullrefformat`. The `labelformat` provides a template for formatting the label, where `A` is a stand-in for the label.  So using `labelformat=A.` says format the label with a period after it. If you wanted the label to be parenthesized, you could specify `labelformat=(A)` for example.

The `fullrefformat` key specifies how references to the label will appear (using ExPex's builtin `\getref` system (which is not the usual LaTeX `\label` and `\ref` system.))  The `fullrefformat` key provides a template for formatting the reference, where X is a stand-in the example number and A is the stand-in for the subexample label. Since the label includes a period (`labelformat=A.`) but we typically don't want the reference to the label to include the `.`, we specify the `fullrefformat` to be `XA`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{marathi}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=devanagarinumerals]{ITF Devanagari}
\usepackage{expex}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\makeatother
\definelabeltype{devanagari}
  {labelgen=list,labellist={अ, आ, इ, ई, उ, ऊ, ए, ऐ, ओ, औ, अं, अः},
  labelformat=A.,fullrefformat=XA,labelalign=left,labelwidth=.92em}

\begin{document}
\lingset{labeltype=devanagari}
\pex
\a\begingl
\gla रामः आम्रफलम् खादति//
\glb राम आंबा खातो//
\glft राम आंबा खातो.//
\endgl
\a\begingl
\gla रामः आम्रफलम् खादति//
\glb राम आंबा खातो//
\glft राम आंबा खातो.//
\endgl
\xe
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Output produced with `expex` is unbeatable in all the example packages. Thank you so much Alan :)

Comment: It would be very helpful for me as well as other users if you explain with comments the parameters used in this definition. i.e. `labelgen=list`, `labelformat=A.`, `fullrefformat=XA`

Comment: @Niranjan I've added some more explanation. All of this is fairly well described in the [ExPex documentation](https://texdoc.net/pkg/expex).

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Comment: Hello, apparently LuaLaTeX with babel does not give me Devanagari numerals as the example counters. See the code added in the question.

Comment: @Niranjan This is a separate question. You can link to this one but ask it as a new question. Your first question was using `xelatex`, `polyglossia` and a problem with the subexample numbering. This is a totally different problem.

Comment: I have changed the title and matter of this question and the new question can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/549168/devanagari-counters-in-package-expex-examples-with-lualatex-and-babel)