# Devanagari counters in package expex examples with LuaLaTeX and babel

Tags: luatex, babel, polyglossia, mapping

This question is an extension to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/548638/devanagari-counters-in-package-expex-subexamples) one. If I run the following code with `LuaLaTeX`, I do not get Devanagari numerals in the example's counter. Whereas I do get them with XeLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifXeTeX
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{marathi}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=devanagarinumerals]{Shobhika}
\else
\ifLuaTeX
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\babelprovide[mapdigits,maparabic]{marathi}
\defaultfontfeatures{Renderer=Harfbuzz,Script=Devanagari}
\babelfont{rm}{Shobhika}
\fi
\fi
\usepackage{expex}
\definelabeltype{devanagari}
{labelgen=list,labellist={अ, आ, इ, ई, उ, ऊ, ए, ऐ, ओ, औ, अं, अः},
    labelformat=A.,fullrefformat=XA,labelalign=left,labelwidth=.92em}

\begin{document}
    \lingset{labeltype=devanagari}
    \pex
    \a\begingl
    \gla रामः आम्रफलम् खादति//
    \glb राम आंबा खातो//
    \glft राम आंबा खातो.//
    \endgl
    \a\begingl
    \gla रामः आम्रफलम् खादति//
    \glb राम आंबा खातो//
    \glft राम आंबा खातो.//
    \endgl
    \xe
\end{document}
```

`XeLaTeX` changes the numbering but `LuaLaTeX` doesn't. Why?

PS - Code can be run with both the compilers. When you change the compiler it requires a second run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a mistake in your code for `babel` and `luatex`. It doesn't work  because your setup for `babel` is not equivalent to that of `polyglossia`. With `polyglossia` you are setting `marathi` as the main language, but not with `babel`. Just make `marathi` the main language:

```
\babelprovide[mapdigits, maparabic, main]{marathi}
```

With this simple fix in your code, the result is exactly the same in both engines: numbers are converted, and the language system for the font is correctly set.

Comment: Oops! It was so simple :P

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out