# Eastern (Hindi) Arabic numerals using Babel and LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, babel, arabic

I am using Babel with LuaLatex. How do I get the all numerals in the date, table of contents, headers, and footers (page numbering), etc. to show as so-called eastern Arabic (Hindi) numberals?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import,main]{arabic}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}[Scale=1.5]{Amiri}

\title{
    \Huge\textsc{اللغة العربية}
}
\author{سالم البوزيدي} 
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\section{تاريخ}

يعود تاريخ علوم الحاسوب إلى اختراع أول حاسوب رقمي حديث. فقبل العشرينات من القرن العشرين، كان مصطلح حاسوب Computer يشير إلى أي أداة بشرية تقوم بعملية الحسابات. ما هي القضايا أو الأشياء التي يمكن لآلة أن تحسبها باتباع قائمة من التعليمات مع ورقة وقلم، دون تحديد للزمن اللازم ودون أي مهارات أو بصيرة (ذكاء)؟ وكان أحد دوافع هذه الدراسات هو تطوير آلات حاسبة computing machines يمكنها إتمام الأعمال الروتينية والعرضة للخطأ البشري عند إجراء حسابات بشرية.

\end{document}
```

Comment: You may also find useful the samples in https://github.com/latex3/babel/tree/master/samples .

Comment: Many thanks for alerting me to these—I'll study them more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. Found an unrelated but similar query [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/549168/devanagari-counters-in-package-expex-examples-with-lualatex-and-babel), and the solution was then confirmed by a paragraph tucked away in the Babel manual under "Digits and counters". Namely, use "mapdigits" as an argument in \babelprovide:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[mapdigits,import,main]{arabic}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}[Scale=1.5]{Amiri}
```

Comment: See Javier Bezos' answer as to why we must (currently) use \babelprovide: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/549682/why-can-arabic-not-be-set-as-the-main-language-with-babel-in-the-package-declara.