# Why can Arabic not be set as the main language with Babel in the package declaration line?

Tags: luatex, babel, arabic

I am trying to understand better how Babel works, especially when used with LuaLaTeX. (For years I used Polyglossia and XeLaTeX).

It appears to me that, for many languages, you simply set the main language when you declare use of Babel, as follows:

```
\usepackage[french]{babel}
```

However, when I try to do the same with Arabic...

```
\usepackage[arabic,bidi=basic]{babel}
```

...the text does not appear, and I get many errors. Instead I find I must use the following:

```
\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import,main]{arabic}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}[Scale=1.5]{Amiri}
```

I am happy to do this of course, but am trying to understand how language declaration works—why declaring Arabic is not the same as declaring, say, French. Many thanks for any clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ‘package interface’ for `ini` based languages has not been yet implemented. That's all . I hope it will be available in a few months, because this is the standard way to select languages in LaTeX. A separate macro to load languages (`\babelprovide`) works, but it's not a good idea in general.

`babel` is introducing a new model to define languages based on `ini` files, as opposed to the old good (but not obsolete) monolithic model based on `ldf` files with self-contained languages, which doesn't always interoperate correctly. Many things have been written from scratch, and Rome was not built in a day . Since `\babelprovide` does the trick, it wasn't one of my priorities.

This doesn't mean the `ldf` model isn't recommended. On the contrary, in monolingual and ‘mostly monolingual’ documents (see the manual for an explanation of the latter) it's still the preferred way to load languages if available. But `ini` files in many languages are as complete as `ldf` files, and in some cases, like `arabic` for `xetex` and `luatex`, even more complete.

Comment: That's very clear and helpful, Javier. As an "end user" rather than someone who can understand what happens behind the curtains, I'll simply wait for Rome to be completed.  Unless there are side effects of which I am not aware, for now I will merrily continue to typeset my Arabic documents using the \babelprovide method.